# How is sample size determined in animal research?

Tags: statistics, animal-cognition, sampling

In human research, we define our universe and estimate the effect size we expect to observe, then we can draw the a sample of a given size.

How is sample size determined for experiments in the animal research field?

Comment: Do you mean 'determine the sample size', not 'draw/estimate the sample size'? Is this question in the context of power analysis?

Comment: @Pavel I tweaked the question in line with what you are expecting.

Comment: Truth is, for many experiments, whether with animals or humans, people don't estimate an effect size or conduct power analysis at all.

Comment: Truth is, for many experiments, people collect data and later wonder what they might do with it.

Answer (score 6):

Determining sample size for an animal experiment is no different than in research with human subjects. What you need to know is the effect size, the significance level and the power (which is the probability that the test detects a significant effect assuming that there is one). The tricky part is getting the effect size (for an interesting discussion have a look at [this thread](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/how-to-estimate-an-expected-effect-size-for-a-planned-psychology-study)). The other two things are chosen by you as the experimenter. An overview paper on power analysis was written by Cohen (1992).

References

Cohen, J. (1992). A power primer. *Psychological Bulletin*, 112(1), 155. [PDF](http://classes.deonandan.com/hss4303/2010/cohen%201992%20sample%20size.pdf)